# What is meant by "Delphi is created in California, so we discourage the use of notation"?

Tags: delphi

I have learned "Object Pascal Style Guide" in the following site.
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280

I cannot understand the following sentence.

"Delphi is created in California, so we discourage the use of notation, except where required in header translations:"

What does this mean?

Comment: You could move forward and study the final revision of *Econos coding standard* published by JEDI group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look a little bit lower down in the article, it clarifies that it's referring to *Hungarian* notation.  Not sure what California has to do with it, but it means that it's considered poor style to use Hungarian notation (prefixing variable names with abbreviations that describe the variable's type) in Delphi code.  Like the example it gives:

```
CORRECT 
  FMyString: string;

INCORRECT
  lpstrMyString: string;
```

Big, unwieldy prefixes like `lpstr` (Long Pointer to STRing) are common in Windows API code.  The point being made here is that Delphi tries to avoid this convention as a way to make the code easier to read.

Comment: "...it clarifies that it's referring to Hungarian notation. Not sure what California has to do with it" Ah, my dear arch-nemesis Mason Wheeler! I've consulted a globe and Hungary is not within the state of California, which probably explains the original remark.

Comment: @alcalde, I wish whoever wrote that consulted some reference too. Hungarian notation was most probably created in Washington.

Comment: This seems contrary to what is seen in most GUI control naming.

Comment: [`Hungarian notation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) was invented in California by Charles Simonyi.

Comment: The reason behind the name, *Hungarian* notation is that in Hungary, the family names preceed the give name, my name would be something like Karlsen Lasse, and does not, as stated by the others here, mean that it was created in Hungary. The notation was invented by Charles Simonyi while working for Xerox '70-'80 or thereabouts.

Comment: In any case, typically you don't need the prefix to tell you the *type* of the variable, the original *useful* meaning, called "Apps Hungarian Notation" was to denote type of value (not the data type, but meaning), like volume, length, distance, weight, etc. Thus it would be easy to read the code and spot mistakes like "volume = length * weight" (when reading the prefixes). The bastard notation, "Systems Hungarian Notation" denotes the data type of the value, typically not that useful, and thus it isn't strange Embarcadero discourages its usage.

Comment: Remember Simonyi was born in Hungary. I remember an interview when he said the name came from a twist on the sentence "it looks Greek to me" - because the names because so difficult to read - and being Simonyi an Hungarian, it became "it looks Hungarian to me" (Hungarian is an Ugro-Finnish language which is very different from most Latin and German languages), hence "Hungarian notation"

Comment: The actual Hungarian notation in the case above is `strMyString: string;` (because in a practical point of view it is not a pointer but a string). It would even be `pstrMyString: ^string;` in the pointer case because in the Win32 era (and I think - but I'm not sure - on Linux also) short and long pointers are outdated. Also prefixing a `field` with `f` is also a bastard version of Hungarian notation but without the advantage of knowing the variable type on first site. _And yes, I believe in Hungarian notation though I started to use it when I worked for a US corporation.(I'm from Hungary)_

Comment: Because Delphi is case insensitive, from the beginning it used some prefixes to avoid conflicts, i.e. MyRec: TMyRec; or PMyRec = ^TMyRec. The F prefix for fields is useful to avoid conflicts with property names when setter/getter are not used: property MyProp read FMyProp write SetMyProp; the real reason is not to tell what type an identifier is, just to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: The Hungarian Notation Simonyi invented is not the kind of Hungarian Notation discussed here, discouraged by Embarcardero and deprecated by Microsoft: see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html